# Creating one for loop for 3 strings

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, python-2.x

So I have a String called 'Number' with 'abf573'. The task is, to find out if the String 'Number' just has characters and numbers from the Hexadecimal System.

My plan was to make a for loop, where we go through each position of the String 'Numbers', to check with an if statement if it is something out of the Hexadecimal System. To check that, I thought about writing down the A-F, a-f and 0-9 into Lists or separat Strings.

My Problem now is, that I have never done something like this in Python. I know how to make for loops and if-/else-/elif-Statements, but I dunno how to implement this in to this Problem.

Would be nice, if someone can give me a hint, how to do it, or if my way of thinking is even right or not.

Comment: Here you go https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Your way of thinking is okay; it would work, although there are easier solutions (like regular expressions).

Comment: **I have a String called 'Number' with 'abf573'** What does this mean?

Comment: Just try and see what happens. Then you can ask concrete questions here.

Comment: @Tim i am assuming he wanted to say Number = "abf573"

Comment: try to write some code and then ask for help :) there is super easy way to test whether a number is hexadecimal or not, but its good to write you own logic first.

Comment: you need to loop over your input string for eg: if name of string is  `'Number' with value = 'abf573'` and test whether this `char` is in `valid_char( string) = abcdefABCDEF012..9` if its not print('invalid') and break the loop.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it quite smart and fast to try to convert this string into an integer using `int()`, and to handle the exception `ValueError` which occurs if it is not possible.
Here is the beautiful short code:

```
my_string = 'abf573'
try:
    result = int(my_string, 16)
    print("OK")
except ValueError:
    print("NOK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are *iterables*. So, you can write

```
Number = '12ab'

for character in Number:
    if character in 'abcdef':
         print('it is HEX')
```

Also, there is an `isdigit` method on strings, so your number is hex is `not Number.isdigit()`